# Product not display in product list page

Tags: product, category, product-list, category-products

I have added products and set quantity is more than zero and stock status set to in stock and products also assign to specific categories but product not display in product list page.

Answer (score 1):

This is a just a quickie – got caught out with a weird issue yesterday where the Magento products in a particular category just disappeared – they still existed if you navigated directly to their URL, but they would not show in their categories (though the Manage Categories screen in the Magento admin still showed those products in their correct category).

These things always happen at inopportune times, I was right about to start a pre-go-live review of a site, and was left with one category completely devoid of products, thanks for making me look like an egg, Magento!

It prompted me to begin a sequence of steps I have found myself often taking to diagnose why products do not appear on the Magento frontend like I expect them to. I thought it might be worth documenting those steps I take and things I check to find out what is preventing a product to show up. Ironically yesterday, I got to the end of my usual list and the products still didn’t show up! So I now have one other thing to suggest you try when products appear to inexplicably stop displaying.

Here we go with my top things to check for when your products don’t show up:

Are the products In Stock?
I know it sounds obvious but when you’re adding a quick test product, it’s easy to miss this field, trust me. Make sure it’s set to In Stock as shown below:
[image]

```
You can also set up the inventory configuration to Display out of stock products, which sort of negates this one if it is set to Yes:
```

[image]

Are the products Enabled?

Again another easy one to miss when adding a product manually, not so easy to stuff up if you use bulk product imports though. Interestingly the fix I eventually found below involved this attribute.
[image]

Are the products Visible?

In some merchandising situations you want your simple products to be invisible and only show the parent products. However if you do want your product to be visible make sure you set it where applicable in this field.
[image]

```
Are any associated products in stock?
Are the products in the expected category?
Are your Caches and Indexes out of date?
```

Access these options in the System -> Cache Management and System -> Index Management menus.
Have you run out of other things to try?
And lastly – the weird situation I had yesterday where the products were visible when navigating directly, but not when looking at their category page (and oddly it only affected one category). I suspect this must be to do with an index table not being correct, or a cache, but I tried re-indexing and refreshing the cache to no avail, so I can’t pin it on this for sure.

Anyway, all it took to have the products re-associate with their category was to bulk disable them and then bulk re-enable them. Strange eh? I had tested a bulk attribute change earlier and that didn’t fix them, so it wasn’t just any attribute change, but particularly the status. I just wish I knew why that fixed them – but I didn’t have time to investigate further, or even try to replicate the issue. So for now It’s a ‘solar flare’ problem…

Got through all of these and still no luck? Let me know. Also I’d appreciate any feedback on other tips or suggestions people may have on this, always good to add another possible fix to my list.

Article Taken:
http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/